# How to find a word in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say you are filtering on rows in a column that contains the word Engineer in a phrase. How can I exclude words like 'Engineering' or 'Engineered' or 'Engineers' when I wouldn't know all the possibilities.

Example rows could contain:

```
1|System Engineering
2|System Engineer
3|System Engineers
4|System Engineer Department
```

So only rows 2 and 4 should appear.

I'm using `WHERE title LIKE '%Engineer%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE title LIKE '%Engineer' OR title LIKE '%Engineer %'
```

The first `WHERE` clause will match phrases like "System Engineer" and the second will match phrases like "System Engineer Department".

Answer (score 0):

Could you try WHERE title LIKE '%Engineer %' (with a space before last %)

This should ensure that Engineer is separated away from other words containing the word.

Comment: But then System Engineer would not be included.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH (search_column1) AGAINST ("Engineer");

UPD:
Link to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)